# How to execute multiple oracle queries using single connection?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have 3 tables in my database and their schema looks something like,

```
Table1 (Col1 Pk, Col2), 
Table2 (Col3 Pk, Col1 FK, Col4)
Table3 (Col5 Pk, Col3 FK, Col6)
```

Here the values of primary key columns is auto incremented on every insert operation. 
I want to insert values in the above tables. With the above scenario i cannot insert into Table3 unless i have value of Col3 (foreign key to Table2), similarly insert into Table2 won't go through unless i have value for Col1 (foreign key to Table1)

Question:
How can i insert into the above tables in a single database connection ?

I can always make 3 different calls and insert values, but how can i use the value from Table1 and use it to insert into Table2, likewise value for Table2 and use it to insert into Table3 in single connection ?

I thought of writing a stored procedure but not sure how can i fetch Col1 value and use it to insert into Table2.

Pls suggest some thoughts here. An example will also help.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558979/inserting-into-oracle-and-retrieving-the-generated-sequence-id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you're looking for this. Just use `Returning` to retrieve the PK value and use the value on next insert

```
declare
    v_col1_id number(10) := null;
    v_col3_id number(10) := null;
begin
    insert into T1 (col2) values ('xxx') RETURNING col1 INTO v_col1_id; -- col1 - PK
    insert into T2 (col1, col4) values (v_col1_id, 'yyy') RETURNING col3 INTO v_col3_id; -- col3 - PK
    insert into T3 (col3, col6) values (v_col3_id , 'zzz'); -- col5 - PK
end;
/
```

Comment: Don't do this. "RETURNING" is a non-standard SQL.

Comment: @battlmonstr Do you have better way to do the same thing ?

Comment: I guess this is fine if you are ok to write a stored procedure anyway. Looking at [solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733085/auto-increment-for-oracle) they are all based on sequence / nextval anyway. Maybe auto-increment in general is not standard, and one have to use various proprietary extensions.

Comment: @VrushankDoshi `Returning` is there for this. If you only used standard SQL, you would go nowhere. What you do, you write RDBMS-specific sql. You write standard when possible and when not possible, you separate. For example, in Sql Server same thing would be achieved by using `OUTPUT INSERTED`. So what we do in code, we just say `object.executeInsert` and these non-standard SQL bits are abstracted to the caller.

Comment: @battlmonstr See comment ^^ above ^^. And then, what if this is Oracle12 and you just use `identity`? Trigger is more maintained. If this code needs to be executed via app, like .NET, you do as I said above. Abstract SQL calls, build sql generating objects or just use entity framework.

Comment: You are right. I'm suprised that there's still no standard for such a basic thing in 2019.

Comment: @battlmonstr In fact, I also support `MySql`. It doesn't have any native support for returning values besides inserted identity. That was a serious hustle to replicate returning values in .net code, so the call can be abstracted among 3 different engines.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have RETURNING . This is MySQL approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112852/get-the-new-record-primary-key-id-from-mysql-insert-query

Comment: @battlmonstr This is exactly what I said. But more over. In sql serv. and Ora, I can return not only PK/identity but **ANY** field. This is what I am talking about